# What's the conserved stress energy tensor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, noethers-theorem, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I've worked on this problem for forever and still don't really see the solution. Any help appreciated.

Say we have the Lagrangian for a scalar field that's $U(1)$ charged,$$\mathcal{L} ={1\over4}(F_{\mu\nu})^2 + |D_\mu\phi|^2 - M^2|\phi|^2,$$where $D_\mu = \partial_\mu - igA_\mu$ and $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$. Calculate the conserved stress energy tensor that follows from invariance of $\mathcal{L}$ under spacetime translations.

Comment: Do you know how to construct conserved quantities from symmetries of $\mathcal{L}$ using Noether's theorem?

Comment: Hi user60434. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.